# Dynamically add answers

Tags: google-apps-script, google-forms, javascript, google-sheets-form-submissions

I want to ask questions as the following with Google Forms:

What lessons have you already completed?
(here I give a list of lesson options. Only one option can be selected)

- Lesson A
- Lesson B
- Lesson C

etc.

When did you begin the lesson?

the user should type 2013

When did you end the lesson?

the user should type 2014

Now, I want to dynamically (with a plus button?) give the user the option to add more lessons and again answer the which lesson, begin/end questions, as we do with JavaScript in an HTML form.

Is there any way to do that with Google Script?

I've seen other questions asking about a small repeated form, but I have a very long form with repeated fields like the one above

Comment: Hi, welcome to WebApps. "I want to dynamically (with a plus button?) give the user the option to add more lessons and again answer the which lesson, begin/end questions [...] Is there any way to do that with Google Script?"  The answer is "no"; this question has been asked many times in many ways.  The solution is always the same: create as many sections as you have potential questions and transfer control to the next section depending on the answer to a question. The solution for  a "very long form" is the same as for a very short form.

Comment: @Tedinoz Actually this is how i implemented till now, and this looks that is the way to go..
Btw for other I have to note that the best way is to create one "good" section and in the end you have to choose one option to go to "next section" and the other "go to final section". As long as you add sections for multiples you dont have to change anything cuz the rooting is change dynamically (i.e. my first "Lesson" section will still have the "go to final section" to go after all the multiples..